# NSAttributedString in NSTextView not showing up unless you scroll

Tags: macos, nsattributedstring, nstextview

I'm trying to set an attributed string in an NSTextView, and if the text is taller than the text view, the text doesn't show up at all unless you scroll the text box.

There aren't many posts about attributed strings in NSTextView, so maybe I'm just doing something wrong. Here's how I'm setting the text:

```
[[self.textView textStorage] appendAttributedString:attributedString];
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to programmatically tell the `NSTextView` it has to make the new string visible:

```
NSUInteger length = [[self.textView string] length];
[self.textView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(length,0)];
```

This should work independent of if the appended string is a "simple" string or an attributed string.

Answer (score 1):

Call `-beginEditing` before making a series of changes to the text storage and `-endEditing` afterward. See [Text System Storage Layer Overview: Changing Text Storage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextStorageLayer/Tasks/ChangingTextStorage.html).